# execute rsync command from shell without prompt for passphrase

Tags: shell, rsync

I have rsync a repository with a remote server and currently, we have passphrase for the security key. How can add the passphrase in the rsync command without a prompt

Answer (score 0):

Look at `man rsync`:

> You can avoid the password prompt by setting the environment variable
>   RSYNC_PASSWORD to the password you want to use or using the --password-file option. This may be useful when scripting rsync.

Comment: alternative for people who doesn't use rsync daemon? or how o setup it.

Comment: @Chumillas This looks a different question than the original post, that might deserve its own post